# Why isn't the browser updating with this real time push in Flask socketIO?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, socket.io

I'm new to Flask and a bit rusty on my Javascript. I have need to generate events in python externally and push them to a web page in realtime, so I've chosen Flask-SocketIO. I've built the simplest example that I can think of:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import Flask, render_template
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, Event    

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'haha!'
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)    

thread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()    

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()    

    def ticker(self):
        print("ticking")
        while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
            text="hi there"
            print(text)
            socketio.emit('message', {'data': text})
            sleep(1)    

    def run(self):
        self.ticker()    

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')    

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    global thread
    print('Client connected')    

    if not thread.isAlive():
        print("Starting Thread")
        thread = MyThread()
        thread.start()    

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

With this index.html file in a templates directory:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ticker</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.send('User has connected!');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(text) {
        $("#messages").append('<li>'+text+'</li>');
        console.log('Received message');
    });
});
</script>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm seeing a list of "hi there"s in the console, but nothing in the browser at localhost:5000. It seems to hang--the bottom of the browser says "Waiting for cache" or Waiting for localhost". Can someone figure out what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm answering this for anyone who is coming across this need to have an external process sending messages to a browser using Flask and socketIO. I spent a lot of time Googling and Stackoverflowing, and I never found a really simple, clean example, so here it is to the best of my ability.

This is what I wanted: to use Python, Flask, and SocketIO and to have an external process running sending messages that would be shown in the browser. My first stab at it was what I wrote as a question, which was to spawn a thread with the external process. What I ended up doing was to have a different Python program be the external process, which for my application, a robotic sensor reporter, is actually better. So, mea culpa, I'm not answering my question *exactly*. But as I wrote, I hope that there's some utility in putting this answer here, because I never found a simple example of how to do that. Here it is.

I think that the essential problem is that you need some sort of load balancing to have an external process sending messages through socketio, as the code doesn't know if it's receiving messages from 1 program or 10,000. The easiest way it ultimately seemed to me to be was to use redis. So you need to have redis up and running when the code is running. On a Mac with Homebrew, you install redis with:

```
$ brew install redis
```

And you run it with

```
$ redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

(There are obviously ways to have it start at boot.) Here's my server code, main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO    

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'slivovitz'
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')    

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here's my external process code, broadcast.py

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import datetime
import time    

socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        msg = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        print(msg)
        socketio.emit('message', msg, broadcast=True)
        time.sleep(1)
```

And here's the html code index.html in the templates directory:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Listener</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect();    

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');
        console.log('Received message');
    });
});
</script>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you're looking to do this whole shenanegan on a Raspberry Pi, install redis with https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-server-on-debian-9_472211. It's just that crazy easy. Enjoy